# QStyledItemDelegate tooltip handling (+ internal status)

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip, qtableview, qstyleditemdelegate

I am using "fancy" QStyledItemDelegate for the first time to draw and control multiple buttons in a QTableView column.
So far so good with the paint + editorEvent approach, but with two little issues/unresolved ideas:

- I can't understand how to handle tooltips... Couldn't find more explicit info than Qt documentation of helpEvent, but not sure how to use it. I tried using the view->model()->setData(), but my model is not supposed to be editable, so I suppose I could "draw" the tooltip when appropriate but don't know how?
- Also, I found some workarounds, but I wanted to check if I overlooked another way to do it: I draw/handle events of my different buttons depending on some model data values. However, it seems all QStyledItemDelegate methods are const, so I can't edit internal data (to avoid code duplication between paint and editorEvent, like set a flag in paint and react to events accordingly to flag value...). Am I missing something? (Without the createEditor/setEditorData approach?)

Comment: As far as I know, `QStyledItemDelegate` doesn't inherit `QWidget`, which has `toolTip` property. That is why you can't set it as you want. The workaround may be to receive `QWidget*` via `QAbstractItemView::indexWidget` and set tooltip for it directly. Not so tricky, but extra code...

Comment: Thx for the suggestion! I actually found an answer for my first point (will add an answer if I also find the second one/some comments point to it), I didn't know about the QToolTip static methods, so it's actually easy to show tooltips on demand when appropriate rect receives the event! (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtooltip.html#showText)

Comment: Yes, that is good point. You can write an [`eventFilter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) in your delegate. Plus it isn't const so you can call functions which will change some data :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show tooltip for index of table, just override data() method of your model class and return text for Qt::ToolTipRole role.